# Bind TextBlock.Text to specific item-property in collection where value matches another binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

Trying to stay on the MVVM road, I keep struggling with the following task for hours:

I want to show the String-value of a specific Item (in a TextBlock), which is part of the UserCollection (`ObservableCollection<Tuple<int, string>>`). The selection should take place via the Int-property of the item in the Collection, matching the bound IdCreatedByUser-Property in MyOrder.
To make things more clear:
An UserCollection that holds an ID (int) and NAME (string):

```cs
public ObservableCollection<Tuple<int, string>> UserCollection;
```

A MyOrder-Property holding an Instance of the Orders-Class:

```cs
public Order MyOrder;
```

Here an example of the Orders-class.

```cs
public class Order: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Comment;
  public int IdCreatedByUser;
  public bool IsComplete;
}
```

Please note that this is just an example for the properties..knowing that get,set are missing here..

The only solution I came up with is to hijack a Combox like this:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding UserCollection}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Item2"
    SelectedValue="{Binding MyOrder.IdCreatedByUser}"
    SelectedValuePath="Item1">

    <ComboBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Item2,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ComboBox.Template>
</ComboBox>
```

The fact that I can use ItemsSource, SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath makes it possible for me to select and show the desired Item. Any solutions for the use of TextBlocks with this one?
I was also thinking about a converter or extra property..but maybe you can show me a way to design this in a better way.. 
Thanks!

Comment: In a web browser, angle brackets are taken to indicate tags. So if you don't put backticks around `ObservableCollection<Tuple<int, string>>` to notify that markdown that it's to be shown literally, it appears as "ObservableCollection>", which isn't what you intended.

Comment: That said, your solution to the problem is fine. I did the same thing yesterday in production code. You could [write a MultiConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) instead and use it with a multibinding, but it wouldn't be much less verbose. You can index a collection in a binding, but only with a literal index value: `{Binding MyColl[1].Foo}` etc.

Comment: The other option is to give your viewmodel a `SelectedUser` property, which returns `UserCollection[MyOrder.IdCreatedByUser]` and raise `PropertyChanged("SelectedUser")` when `MyOrder` or `MyOrder.IdCreatedByUser` changes.

Comment: That is also a nice way to do it. The problem here is that I have more Controls to show me the Name of a specific User..like a property IdFinishedByUser, IdEditedByUser and so on in the Orders-Class. So i have to handle more properties in my Viewmodel and I wanted to prevent this..are there any problems with my ComboBox hijack regarding to the normal use of TextBlocks?

Comment: I don't think there would be any issues with it. One thing I'd consider though would be to write a ComboBox style to simplify the XAML, if you're doing a bunch of these. I'll strip down the one I did yesterday and post it.

Comment: that would be nice! i noticed some different behaviour regarding to the normal TextBlock..like other highlighting color and stuff. Maybe i can also solve this via a template!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This essentially makes your specialized ComboBox easily reusable. Stuff like `FontWeight` will be inherited by the `ContentPresenter`.

```
<Style x:Key="CollectionLookupComboBox" TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
    <!-- 
    Default to readonly, but you can override that for particular instances 
    if that's useful somewhere. 
    -->
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border
                                x:Name="OuterBorder"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Background="Transparent"
                                >
                                <!-- 
                                The margin here keeps the text in the same spot when I toggle IsReadOnly,
                                with the default theme I have. May need to fiddle with that to get it to 
                                look right for you. 
                                -->
                                <ContentPresenter 
                                    Margin="3,2,2,0"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                    ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    />
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Example -- this is overkill; you don't need an ItemTemplate or boldface, but it demonstrates how all the usual ComboBox stuff is supported:

[image] [image]

```
<StackPanel 
    Orientation="Vertical"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    >
    <CheckBox
        x:Name="ReadOnlyCheckBox"
        IsChecked="True"
        Margin="1"
        Content="Read-Only" 
        />
    <ComboBox
        Margin="1"
        Style="{StaticResource CollectionLookupComboBox}"
        IsReadOnly="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ReadOnlyCheckBox}"
        MinWidth="80"
        SelectedIndex="0"
        FontWeight="Bold"
        Foreground="Green"
        >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="DeepSkyBlue" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4">
                    <Label Content="{Binding}" />
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <sys:String>First Item</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Second Item</sys:String>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```